# SQL: list items not sold in between time period

Tags: sql, sql-server

The software we use has two tables for orders, Orders and OrderItems. 
I am trying do run a query on the database to show which items have not sold in a period of time.
This is what I have but It's not working ( it brings up all the records)

```
SELECT
OrderItem.Name,
OrderItem.SKU,
[Order].OrderDate

FROM
[Order]
INNER JOIN OrderItem ON [Order].OrderID = OrderItem.OrderID

WHERE
(OrderItem.SKU NOT IN
      (SELECT DISTINCT OrderItem.SKU WHERE ([Order].OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-09-08' AND '2014-01-01')))
```

Comment: can you provide your table structure. What are the columns in OrderItem and OrderDate?

Comment: You probably don't want to use `BETWEEN`  - see https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common  and https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT oi.Name, oi.SKU, max(o.OrderDate) as lastOrderDate
FROM [Order] o INNER JOIN
     OrderItem oi
     ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
GROUP BY oi.Name, oi.SKU
HAVING sum(case when o.OrderDate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-09-08' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If you are just looking for orders before this year, it is easier to write the `having` clause as:

```
HAVING max(o.OrderDate) < '2014-01-01'
```

Comment: Thank You! I still have a small problem though, When I do this without the oi.Name it works but when I add the name with the exact code, it returns all the rows instead of just the ones that I need which were returned before.

Comment: @JayLamay . . . That doesn't make sense, unless a `SKU` could have multiple names.

Answer (score 1):

Flip your dates. It should be [Begin Date] Between [End Date]

```
WHERE (OrderItem.SKU NOT IN
      (SELECT DISTINCT OrderItem.SKU
       WHERE ([Order].OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-09-08')))
```

Comment: Do you really expect this to work without a `from` clause?  This query will probably work as written, but I believe it will return no rows.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
SELECT oi.Name, oi.SKU, o.OrderDate
FROM [Order] o 
INNER JOIN OrderItem oi ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
WHERE oi.SKU NOT IN
(
  SELECT os.SKU 
  FROM [Order] os
  INNER JOIN OrderItem ois ON os.OrderID = ois.OrderID
  WHERE os.OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-09-08'
)
```

You have to join to the `OrderItem` table in the sub query in order to get the `SKU`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your query was build 'upside down'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SKU FROM OrderItem oi
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM Order o
    JOIN OrderItem oi2 ON  o.OrderID = oi2.OrderID
    WHERE oi2.SKU = oi.SKU
    AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN  '2014-01-01' AND '2014-09-08' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should have another table containing your distinct items, so you could write the following query to see which items were not sold during a certain period (and may have never been sold at all).

```
select i.SKU from items
where not exists (
    select 1 from OrderItem oi
    join Order o on o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
    where oi.SKU = i.SKU
    and o.OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2014-09-08'
)
```

if you don't have such a table, you can select all products that have been ordered at some point, but not during another period

```
select i.SKU from (
  select distinct oi.SKU from OrderItem oi
) i
where not exists (
  select 1 from OrderItem oi
  join Order o on o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
  where oi.SKU = i.SKU
  and o.OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2014-09-08'
)
```